# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() yii-app-basic

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I've one module -> users.

```
->modules
    ->users
        ->controllers
        ->models
        ->views
        ->Users.php
```

I created one 'config.php' inside 'config' folder of 'users' modules.

```
->modules
    ->users
        ->config
            ->config.php
        ->controllers
            -> List of Controllers
        ->models
            -> List of models
        ->views
            -> List of Views
        ->Users.php
```

And, i gave directory path of config.php in init() method of Users.php, as

**modules/users/Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\users;

class Users extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\users\controllers';
    public $commonModel = 'app\modules\users\models\Users';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        \Yii::configure($this,require(__DIR__.'/config/config.php'));
    }
}
```

But, it is giving error like

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>   "Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()".

Screenshot

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am taking reference from [Yii2.0 Guide](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2-guide.pdf) to include a path inside init() method.

Please help me to rectify this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: show full screen shot of error page.

Comment: I updated my question with full screenshots of error Mr @IncognitoSkulll

Comment: for which purpose you are creating `config.php`

Comment: I'm having register mail, forgot password mail, and re-send confirmation link in one controller. My senior asked me to make one config.php and write all mail subject and body there. So, i'm trying to do that @IncognitoSkulll

Comment: refer this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#configure%28%29-detail. It says your second argument must be name-value pair.

Comment: Icognito is correct, you need to pass in the array that is built in your config.php file, not the file or path itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you're passing in the PHP code to your config file, instead of passing in a configuration array

Instead of this...

```
\Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__.'/config/config.php'));
```

Try doing this...

```
$config = require(__DIR__.'/config/config.php');
\Yii::configure($this, $config);
```

In your `config.php` file you should be returning an array, if you're using the basic-app config file and adding to that then it should be set up like this already

Comment: Hey lynch, i got this error now syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE)

Comment: Could you post the code for the function, that error would suggest to me there's an error above the `require` line that's throwing this exception

Comment: Yeah lynch. <?php

namespace app\modules\users;

class Users extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\users\controllers';
    public $commonModel = 'app\modules\users\models\Users';
    
    public $config = require(__DIR__.'/config/config.php');
    
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        
        \Yii::configure($this, $config);
    }
}

Comment: Take the `public $config = require...` line out from where it is now, and put it into the init() function, before the `Yii::configure` call. If you try to use require to set a default property it will throw an exception

Comment: Yeah. Now syntax error not coming. but, invalid argument supplied foreach() error continues to come. Here is my code. <?php

namespace app\modules\users;

class Users extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\users\controllers';
    public $commonModel = 'app\modules\users\models\Users';
    
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $config = require(__DIR__.'/config/config.php');
        \Yii::configure($this, $config);
    }
}

Comment: Most likely then you're not returning an array in your config file, are you using the config file that comes as standard with Yii or your own?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92735/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-lynch).

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the configuration file. The configureation file must returns an array. Make sure that the config file is as follows:

```
<?php

$config = [
    'name1' => 'value1',
    'name2' => [/* something here */],
];

return $config;
```

Comment: what value i can pass in place of name1 and name2 Mr @Houmam.??

Comment: You can put your configuration data, check this link, it will help you: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/config/web.php

Answer (score 1):

you edit file model and delete code:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return DriverSearch the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    return new DriverSearch(get_called_class());
}
```